# How to let a user securely access files on the server

Tags: php, file

I'm working on a web app that allows scientists to submit to a high performance computing cluster through a web interface. The users fill in some data about their experiment, upload some files and the web app takes care of the rest.

At the end of the computation the users need to be able to access their resultant files. They are around 1 GIG in size.

I want to allow the users to browse these files but I don't know how to do it securely. Users should not be able to browse files that are not theirs.  The files are already stored in a directory outside of webroot and owned by the Apache user.

I'm working in PHP, any advice on how to implement something like this?

Comment: there might be plenty user authentication and permission management PHP libraries/frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction is, don't do it-go and get help.  Security is not a job for the ill-prepared, no matter how well meaning.  You need a consultant expert to advise and implement this portion, and then provide you with an authentication framework and API to the data.

Remember the recent global warming email scandal-scientific data may be sensitive.

Comment: +1 on this... it's not that hard to do, but really must be done right.  And there are already plenty of people to ask in the HPC community.  My suggestion is WebDAV over HTTPS and an LDAP server for authentication, and you should be able to find packages for setting that up properly.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest storing the files in distinct directories (by permission) and then opening up an FTP server with SSL for browsing/downloading the results.

Comment: This might be secure, but the drawback is that a (typically an OS-level) user account is needed for each user of the web application. This is fine for intranet scenarios but fails if the application is open to the internet.